# Which object counts as the 'camera' in Python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

In python turtle graphics, which object counts as the camera?
such as how in 2D videogames the view of the map follows the player as he \ she moves around.

Comment: check out pygame

Answer (score 1):

There's no camera. Turtle graphics don't have that.